Help to debug no internet on debian after restart
There's other questions similar to mine, but some of the answers don't work for me, or some just resolved on their own.
I have Debian 11 with no DE installed. I restarted it and it doesn't have internet. Here's what's up:
Symptoms:

Doesn't even connect to the router
No ip address. See output of ip a

ping 1.1.1.1 returns ping: connect: Network is unreachable
output of cat /etc/resolv.conf


What I've tried

Moving the SSD to different machines to test to see if it was the hardware
Restarting the router
Changed the LAN IP subnet, in hopes that this would reassign it an IP address
sudo service networking restart from this post

More info about this computer

Not a new install. This machine is mainly used to sync files between 2 other computers and my phone.
I installed Debian on it last year (or year before?). I don't remember how I configured the network or where the values in /etc/resolv.conf came from.
I do have my router set to use Cloudflare's DNS
It had been on for for almost a year prior working fine. I had to move it, so it got restarted
I had some port-forwarding rules for this computer that I've removed when debugging this issue

Other answers on this site want me to use things that I don't have installed. I.e., I don't have ifconfig installed: ifconfig: command not found
I would love any help on how I could even start to debug this issue.

Start with ip link set dev enp8s0  up and ip addr add 192.168.1.99/24 dev enp8s0 replacing the address/netmask with an appropriate value for this host on your network. Can you ping the router? Then add a route, ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp8s0 replacing the address with that of your router

If that works you need to identify why you weren't able to get an address. Do you offer DHCP? Is your host expecting to use DHCP?

@ChrisDavies That worked! Amazing. What did I do exactly? I also don't know how to find out if I offer DHCP or if my host is expecting to use DHCP.

I updated, then restarted and no network again.

Those commands demonstrate that your network has the capability to work. If you've restarted you'll need to run them again. Where did the values in /etc/resolv.conf come from? Did you edit those in yourself or did the system add them? How did you configure the network during installation? Please edit your question to explain this

Is this a new installation? If so, then why are you using Bullseye (11) instead of the current Bookworm (12)? If not, what has changed to stop the network connecting?

@ChrisDavies I edited the question.

The most basic way to configure network interfaces in Debian is using the /etc/network/interfaces file (or files in the /etc/network/interfaces.d directory in newer releases): what's in that file/those files?

If those files contain nothing referring to your enp8s0 network interface, then either you had simply done nothing to make the network configuration persist over a reboot, or you have some other network configuration management system like NetworkManager (package network-manager) or Netplan (package netplan.io) in use, but perhaps improperly configured.

/etc/network/interfaces.d/ is empty. /etc/network/interfaces file contains reference to enp3s0, not enp8s0. I updated it to the latter and now I have internet after a reboot. Editing this file solved my problem.
